# Working out a rolling average where you don't always divide by the total count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, average

I am trying to work out a rolling average for batsmen in cricket. Anyone who knows the sport will know that the average is worked out as runs scored / innings, unless a batsmen is not out. If a batsmen plays 2 innings, and is 'not out' in 1 of those, their average would be worked out as

```
runs scored innings 1 + runs scored innings 2 / 1
```

If they were out in both innings, the calculation would be

```
runs scored innings 1 + runs scored innings 2 / 2
```

This is easy enough to work for an overall average, however I would like to calculate this as a running average. I have done this before using a loop and calculating the average for each row individually, but can anyone suggest a way to do this using any built in functions?

Current code example:

```
with cte as (
select 
Innings_Player, 
Innings_Runs_Scored, 
Innings_Date, 
CASE WHEN Innings_Runs_Scored = "DNB" THEN null WHEN Innings_Runs_Scored LIKE "%*%" THEN REPLACE(Innings_Runs_Scored,"*","") ELSE Innings_Runs_Scored END AS RunsNum,
CASE WHEN Innings_Runs_Scored LIKE "%*%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NotOutFlag,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY Innings_Date) as RN
from TABLE
where Innings_Player = "JE Root"
AND Innings_Runs_Scored IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Innings_Date
)
,cte2 as
(
select
 *,
   SUM(CAST(RunsNum AS INT64)) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) AS RunningTotal,
   AVG(CAST(RunsNum AS INT64)) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) AS RunningAvg,
 from cte
 where runsNum IS NOT NULL AND runsNum <> "TDNB"
)

select * from cte2
```

Resulting dataset:

[image: dataset]

So, the average is not correct. For the rolling average, the calcuation for row three should be innings_run_scored for the first three rows, divided by 2 rather than 3, as you can see from the NotOutFlag, that the 3 innings in the list was a not out.

Similarly, row 4 should be divided by 3, row 5 by 4, and then as row 6 was a not out as well, row 6 should be divided by 4, row 7 by 5 etc etc. I think the equation would be

```
Innings_Run_Scored / Innings - Not Out Count
```

Comment: Sample input data and the expected output would greatly help your question.

Comment: Hi Tim, there is a screenshot of what the data looks like, and then underneath it explains what it should be. Cheers, Gareth.

Comment: @gsweet87 . . . Your question and your data are not really consistent.  The query has much more logic than the question, which makes it pretty hard to even start.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the query shows how I am calculating the current rolling average, but the question is how can i calculate the rolling average but taking the 'NotOutFlag' away from the count used to calculate the mean. I don't think i'm explaining it too well, because it is quite complicated. Would you be able to elaborate a little more on where exactly the confusion is, and then I can edit the question?

Comment: @gsweet87 . . . Tim already explained.  Show sample data.  Show the results you want.  Explain the logic that you want to implement in terms of the data you provide.

Answer (score 0):

`AVG` is basically a `SUM / COUNT` Since you want to alter the `COUNT` portion I would suggest forgoing the use of the AVG function. You can count using a `SUM` with `CASE` to count only the cases where `NotOutFlag` is `0`

so the line

```
   AVG(CAST(RunsNum AS INT64)) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) AS RunningAvg,
```

would become

```
   SUM(CAST(RunsNum AS INT64)) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) 
/  SUM(CASE WHEN NotOutFlag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN)
AS RunningAvg,
```

Of course you will need to add some more logic to avoid division by 0.

```
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN NotOutFlag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) = 0 
THEN 0 
ELSE 
SUM(CAST(RunsNum AS INT64)) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) 
/  
SUM(CASE WHEN NotOutFlag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Innings_Player ORDER BY RN) 
END  AS RunningAvg,
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, i'll have a play around with this this evening.